# How to export a 3D coloured model file from LiDAR Meshes from sceneUnderstanding iOS14?

Tags: ios, arkit, metal, realitykit, lidar

I was trying to export the mesh file visible by sceneUnderstanding and thanks to stackoverflow i was succeed. But the output is white and it is not that much clear and understand easily. So i started my try for coloured file export for the sample code provided by Apple developers but not succeed on it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/world_tracking/visualizing_and_interacting_with_a_reconstructed_scene

Is there any way that i can export a .obj file with .mtl and .jpeg file or any file extension which gives me the coloured output. Any code, link or suggestion will be appretiated.